# Forcing a Horizontal Description list in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter Bootstrap v3.2.0 to lay out my page.  I have the following Description List and it displays fine in all the responsive views except the extra small view.  How can I force a horizontal display in that view as well?

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Stack:</dt>
    <dd>461mm</dd>
    <dt>Reach:</dt>
    <dd>389mm</dd>
</dl>
```

Correct Layout (In all views except XS)

[image]

Incorrect Layout (In xs view)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this in your code now:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
}
```

and put it outside the media query:

```
 .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
```

Comment: thanks.  I figured it was something relatively straight forward.